# How to reconnect node to the cluster after shutting them down with Shutdown commabd

Tags: redis

I have 2 instance of redis running as a service on 3 server

Server 1  redis:7000 redis:7001

Server 2  redis:7000 redis:7001

Server 3  redis:7000 redis:7001

my redis.conf file is as follows

```
port 7000
dir /var/lib/redis/7000/
appendonly no
protected-mode no
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-node-timeout 5000
cluster-config-file /etc/redis/cluster/7000/nodes_7000.conf
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis_7000.pid
logfile /var/log/redis/redis_7000.log
loglevel notice
```

in

/etc/redis/cluster/7000/redis_7000.conf

/etc/redis/cluster/7001/redis_7001.conf

then i connect the cluster using

redis-cli --cluster create ip1:7000 ip2:7000 ip3:7000 ip1:7001 ip2:7001 ip3:7001 --cluster-replicas 1

It all works well

but the issue is I couldn't figure out how to safely shutdown the cluster and again restart the cluster

After i shutdown the cluster from the redis-cli and to restart it I stop the redis instance from each server and remove the node_7000.conf file and then start them again.

when I try to connect this cluster again I get the ERROR

```
[ERR] Node IP1:7000 is not empty. Either the node already knows other nodes (check with CLUSTER NODES) or contains some key in database 0.
```

Now to resolve this I have to flush the data in the the particular node but i dont want to do this i just want to stop and start the cluster with same config. how do I do this?